# `eval` declaration instantiation when calling context is evaluating formal parameter initializers

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, scope, eval, executioncontext

The note below the [PerformEval](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-performeval) abstract operation says:

> The eval code cannot instantiate variable or function bindings in the
> variable environment of the calling context that invoked the eval **if
> the calling context is evaluating formal parameter initializers** or if
> either the code of the calling context or the eval code is strict mode
> code. Instead such bindings are instantiated in a new
> VariableEnvironment that is only accessible to the eval code. Bindings
> introduced by let, const, or class declarations are always
> instantiated in a new LexicalEnvironment.

**Question:**

What is meant by "if the calling context is evaluating formal parameter initializers"? What is a "parameter initializer"?

There is only one other reference to the term "parameter initializer" in the spec in [Note 3 of 9.2.10](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-functiondeclarationinstantiation). This note says:

> Parameter Initializers may contain direct eval expressions. Any top
> level declarations of such evals are only visible to the eval code
> (10.2). The creation of the environment for such declarations is
> described in 14.1.22.

I interpreted this as meaning that if a parameter initializer expression contains an eval call, then any variables created inside that eval call are not instantiated in the parameter scope. So, in the example below, I was expecting a `ReferenceError` to be thrown since `c` shouldn't be instantiated in the parameter scope:

```
function t(a = eval('var c = 8'), b = () => c) {
  console.log(b())
}

t() // 8
```

But as you can see from the console output, my interpretation isn't correct. Even though `c` was created inside an eval call, its value is still visible to the funarg defined by `b` and can thus be printed to the console.

Comment: Both Chrome and FF produce the same unexpected results. I may be misunderstanding it too, but it's possible that this is a bug in their implementations. This is a *very* edge case, after all.

Comment: Your interpretation of the note seems right. I wonder if that note is just wrong? The spec text itself uses the function's overall `VariableEnvironment`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out you found a specification bug! I asked in TC39's Matrix chat and they've created a PR to remove this note:

https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/pull/2428

The behavior in the note *used* to be correct, but was removed in 2017 in https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/pull/1046

Comment: Thank you for following up so quickly @loganfsmyth! Will the entire note be removed or just the portion relating to "parameter initializers"? The other scenario in the note about the calling context or eval code using strict mode is still correct, but perhaps redundant as it's just putting into words what's going on in steps 13-15 of the algorithm, yes?

Comment: It is removing the "if the calling context is evaluating formal parameter initializers" part from the first note and removing the entire "Note 3" that you linked as well.